# Boostrap grid system not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to position products on a product page with the bootstrap using rows and columns but its not really working anymore since I added a category bar to the page.

As you can see in the picture, product is stacked under the category bar and the other product is next to the category bar. But I want the products to be next to the category bar and I don't know what I'm doing wrong

[image]

So basically I want 4 products on every column next to the sidebar.
This is my code:

```
    <?php   include_once ('templates/header.php');  ?>

<!-- Alle cadeaus gele title bovenaan pagina -->

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 bg-warning" style="font-size:25px">
            <center>Alle cadeaus</center>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>

 <hr />

<br>

<!-- Cadeau categorie side menu -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="categorymenu">
                    <center>  <h3>Categorieën</h3> </center>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <?php foreach (get_categories_h() as $category) : ?>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <a href="#"> <?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
                                </a> 
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>




<!-- Laat cadeau zien op alle cadeaus pagina -->

<?php foreach($products as $product) : ?>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div id="product">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
          <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product['product_foto_thumb']; ?>">
        </a>
        <div class="product_naam"><?php echo $product['product_naam']; ?></div>
        <div class="ophaal_plaats">
           <?php  echo $product['ophaal_plaats']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="aangeboden_door">
            <p>Aangeboden door: Peter</p>
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
         </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>





<div class="clearfix"></div>

 <?php   include_once ('templates/footer.php');  ?>
```

css information:

```
#categorymenu {
    color:black;
    background-color: #D9e5f7;
    padding:10px;
    width:250px;

}

#categorymenu ul li a {
    color:black !important;
}

#categorymenu ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

#product {
    background-color:#ccdcff!important;
    width:176px!important;
    height:230px!important;
    padding:4px;
}
```

Comment: Can you change col-sm-4" to col-sm-2 and check it .We need rest of the  styles to understand it properly.

Comment: @JohnDoe122 Can you add it to fiddle if possible so that its easier to test

Comment: if I change it to col-sm-2 the picture next to the sidebar gets closer to the sidebar

Comment: 1 Sec Ill edit my question and add some styles to it

Comment: What do you mean with fiddle?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue - but a suggestion - <center></center> has been deprecated and should not be used - - rather you should add a simple style rule to your css - .bg-warning{text-align:center}

Comment: Probably, you to need to change the width of product / categorymenu in order to have 3 or 4 cards in a row.

Comment: You also need to work out if you are using BS 3 or 4 - the grid classes nomenclature is different in BS4

Comment: I changed the width of the category sidemenu to 100px and one picture still goes under the category menu bar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this html structure

```css
#categorymenu {
    color:black;
    background-color: #D9e5f7;
    padding:10px;
    width:250px;

}

#categorymenu ul li a {
    color:black !important;
}

#categorymenu ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

#product {
    background-color:#ccdcff!important;
    width:176px!important;
    height:230px!important;
    padding:4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<?php   include_once ('templates/header.php');  ?>

<!-- Alle cadeaus gele title bovenaan pagina -->

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 bg-warning" style="font-size:25px">
            <center>Alle cadeaus</center>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>

 <hr />

<br>

<!-- Cadeau categorie side menu -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div id="categorymenu">
                    <center>  <h3>Categorieën</h3> </center>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        
                            <li class="col-sm-3 list-group-item">
                                <a href="#"> <?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
                            </li>
                            
                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>




<!-- Laat cadeau zien op alle cadeaus pagina -->

        <div class="col-sm-8 row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div id="product">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
          <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product['product_foto_thumb']; ?>">
        </a>
        <div class="product_naam"><?php echo $product['product_naam']; ?></div>
        <div class="ophaal_plaats">
         
        </div>
        <div class="aangeboden_door">
            <p>Aangeboden door: Peter</p>
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-sm-3">
  <div id="product">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
          <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product['product_foto_thumb']; ?>">
        </a>
    <div class="product_naam">
      <?php echo $product['product_naam']; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="ophaal_plaats">

    </div>
    <div class="aangeboden_door">
      <p>Aangeboden door: Peter</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <div id="product">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
          <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product['product_foto_thumb']; ?>">
        </a>
    <div class="product_naam">
      <?php echo $product['product_naam']; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="ophaal_plaats">

    </div>
    <div class="aangeboden_door">
      <p>Aangeboden door: Peter</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <div id="product">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
          <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product['product_foto_thumb']; ?>">
        </a>
    <div class="product_naam">
      <?php echo $product['product_naam']; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="ophaal_plaats">

    </div>
    <div class="aangeboden_door">
      <p>Aangeboden door: Peter</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
        </div>
        </div>
         </div>


<div class="clearfix"></div>

 <?php   include_once ('templates/footer.php');  ?>
```

Comment: If you add in https://jsfiddle.net/ it will be easier to us to find the exact issue . otherwise you can't get exact answer coz php code is also included in your html

Comment: mine and some other answers added here are correct according to my view based on your question

Comment: and you mentioned tags as bootstrap 3 and bootstrap 4 which version you using? there is lot of difference in both

Comment: can you add version of bootstrap?

Comment: This is my version of bootstrap:  Bootstrap v3.3.7

Comment: it supports only html css and js. try to paste my html code and add php to it

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/pezb4bgr/1/ same code you added and i have not touched php. you may copy paste it and test

Comment: Could you convert you're code and change it to my php code with foreach loop?

Comment: I tried the code and it still doesn't work somehow. Its really weird. Still 1 product next to the category menu bar and all the other products are under the category bar

Comment: remove two closing `div` s before closing of foreach loop. you added those extra divs check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pezb4bgr/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you always want 4 products at the right side of the "categorieen" I think you need to change col-md-3 to col-md-2 in the php foreach loop. The total needs to be 12 so 4 + 4*2 = 12. Also, you should never use !important in your css.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the below code. I haven't tested it yet but you can give it a try.

```
<!-- Cadeau categorie side menu -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <div id="categorymenu">
                    <center>  <h3>Categorieën</h3> </center>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <?php foreach (get_categories_h() as $category) : ?>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <a href="#"> <?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
                                </a> 
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>




<!-- Laat cadeau zien op alle cadeaus pagina -->
<div class="col-md-8">
 <div class="row">
  <?php foreach($products as $product) : ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div id="product">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
          <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product['product_foto_thumb']; ?>">
        </a>
        <div class="product_naam"><?php echo $product['product_naam']; ?></div>
        <div class="ophaal_plaats">
           <?php  echo $product['ophaal_plaats']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="aangeboden_door">
            <p>Aangeboden door: Peter</p>
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
         </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>





<div class="clearfix"></div>

 <?php   include_once ('templates/footer.php');  ?>
```

Comment: I don't know why but all the css is being removed if I use this code

Comment: I didn't get your point. You are saying bootstrap styles are removed?

Comment: Did you include bootstrap and your external stylesheet?

Comment: But when i use this piece of code all the products go crazy everywhere

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain the `col-sm` and `col-md`. You need to maintain these equally. In top you've used `col-sm-4` then `col-md-3` without equally partition, I can't understand that.

See the systems for your partitioning-

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-3">
           ...
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3">
           ...
           </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
           ...
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3">
           ...
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in your case that may be in,

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Cadeau categorie side menu -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="categorymenu">
                    <center>  <h3>Categorieën</h3> </center>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <a href="#"> Category 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <a href="#"> Category 2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div id="product">
                        <a href="#">
                          <img src="#">
                      </a>
                      <div class="product_naam">Pro Name</div>
                      <div class="ophaal_plaats">
                         Ophaal
                     </div>
                     <div class="aangeboden_door">
                        <p>Aangeboden door: Peter</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div id="product">
                    <a href="#">
                      <img src="#">
                  </a>
                  <div class="product_naam">Pro Name</div>
                  <div class="ophaal_plaats">
                     Ophaal
                 </div>
                 <div class="aangeboden_door">
                    <p>Aangeboden door: Peter</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="product">
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="#">
              </a>
              <div class="product_naam">Pro Name</div>
              <div class="ophaal_plaats">
                 Ophaal
             </div>
             <div class="aangeboden_door">
                <p>Aangeboden door: Peter</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>        

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div id="product">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="#">
          </a>
          <div class="product_naam">Pro Name</div>
          <div class="ophaal_plaats">
             Ophaal
         </div>
         <div class="aangeboden_door">
            <p>Aangeboden door: Peter</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

</div>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: I have just checked the above code and worked in my PC.. 4 colums in the right.. Have you tested the above code?